# How to run "install-build-deps.sh" for Chromium Building

Tags: debian, chromium-os

I am trying to build chromium from source. Before `gclient sync`, I try running `install-build-deps.sh`. But I can't fix this error:

> Package libc6-dev:armhf is not available, but is referred to by
>   another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'libc6-dev:armhf' has no installation candidate
>   E: Unable to locate package linux-libc-dev
>
> You will have to install the above packages yourself.

I try `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev:armhf`, but it isn't working.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to U&L . What is your operating system?

Comment: @GAD3R hi, my operating system is Debian GNU/Linux 8.9 (jessie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add armhf architecture

```
dpkg --add-architecture armhf
apt-get update
apt-get install libc6-dev:armhf
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But now, when i try "ninja -C out/Release chrome" this error comes:

/home/debian/chromium/depot_tools/ninja: line 26: getconf: command not found
/home/debian/chromium/depot_tools/ninja: line 30: /home/debian/chromium/depot_tools/ninja-linux: No such file or directory 

I never see this error.

Comment: @Secil You need to install the `libc-bin` package